# Python: how to use 'exec' with custom scope?

Tags: python

I need to execute some dynamically generated code in Python and ensure that this code will have access to some custom global values, for example 'bar'. Based on python documentation i assembled the following test code:

```
def foo() : print( globals() )
exec "foo()" in dict( globals(), bar = 1 )
```

According to documentation, calling `foo()` from `exec` with `bar` added to scope will list `bar` among `globals()` inside `foo()` body. But the actual output is:

```
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'C:\\Users\\Eye\
\Documents\\first.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <func
tion foo at 0x01DD40F0>, '__doc__': None}
```

No `bar` here :(. How to make `bar` accessible from within code executed in `exec`?

Comment: @NiklasB. Why not? Did you try it? It is perfectly valid to have an expression `(globals())` and print that.

Comment: @glglgl: Hm, I guess you're right :) Still, this is not really good style, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a suitable solution:

```
def foo() : print( foo.bar )
exec "foo.bar = bar\n" + "foo()" in dict( globals(), bar = 1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

(I'm skipping here a usual rant about how generally bad and insecure is `exec`)

If you try this:

```
exec "print globals().get('bar')" in dict( globals(), bar = 1 )
```

you will see that it works as expected.

When you define a function, it's bound with it's module's namespace, that's what it sees as globals. You can reach those bindings via `foo.func_globals`. That's how a function can access module internals via globals, but cannot see the caller's environment (where `bar` is defined).

Comment: I can't see `foo.func_globals` to contain `bar` either :(. My point is to call external function from `exec`, not just a bare `print`.

Comment: That's the whole point, `foo.func_globals` is what `globals()` returns, and that's fixed at the `foo` compilation time. `bar` is defined in the calling context and you cannot access it from the function without some deep magic. That's the same as when you call `foo` from `other_module.baz` having `bar` an `other_module`'s global.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#globals), when globals() is called from within a function it returns the dictionary for **the module in which the function was defined**.

If you create the new global AND pass it as an argument, you should be able to call functions dynamically. For example,

```
def foo(bar):
  print bar

exec "foo(bar)" in dict(globals(), bar = "hello")
```

Comment: If i change the code to just access global object `bar` it will be "undefined".

Comment: The issue is that once `foo` is defined its globals are fixed. The new variables you pass in are only available within the quoted part of the `exec` statement, in this case `"foo(bar)"`. I think you may only be able to do it if you pass the new variables as arguments to the function.

Comment: Am i correct what it's not important what i'm supplying in dictionary after `in` keyword - functions outside `exec` quotes will not be able to access this information?

Comment: The code inside the quotes will be able to access the new globals in the dictionary, but any functions you call will use the globals that were there when the function was defined. In order to pass new variables to these functions you will need to pass them as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, what is the problem with this?

```
def foo() : print( globals() )
bar = 1
exec "foo()"
{'bar': 1, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <function foo at 0x7fd1b3954ed8>, '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: The problem is that OP wants to provide custom globals to the function, which would require nasty hacks, as far as I know.